# Como selecciono la base de datos a la que me quiero conectar en Nodejs?

Tags: sql, nodejs, express, sequelize.js

Tengo 2 Bases de Datos y una app desarrollada con nodejs, expressjs,sequelize angular y SqlServer. Necesito que al momento de acceder a la app yo pueda seleccionar la base de datos a la que quiero acceder.
Por ejemplo: Tengo las bases de datos DB2018 y DB2019 al momento de acceder a la app necesito poder seleccionar la base de datos a la que quiero acceder.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores te ha marcado?

Comment: Solo estoy trabajando con una Base de datos no tengo problemas. Pero necesito poder seleccionar entre 2 o mas base de datos para trabajar con ellas.

Comment: Necesito poder acceder a otra base de datos desde la misma app.

Answer (score 1):

1. Lo que debes hacer es tener almacenados los datos de la conexion por cada base de datos, esto lo puedes tener en un archivo .js, variables de entorno o inclusive en otra base de datos, el punto es que leas de algun lado dichos datos por cada conexion.
2. Debes de crear una instancia de sequelize como esto:

   const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
     host: 'localhost',
     dialect: /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */
   });

Pasándole los valores: nombre de la BD, username, password, y el server de la BD

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/getting-started.html

Comment: No te recomiendo que lo tengas en un archivo .js, seria bueno si tienes una tercer base de datos en donde almacenes las conexiones a las diferentes base de datos, si esto se complica, la opcion ideal es tenerlo todo en variables de entorno: DB_1="", username_1="", password_1="", host_1="", y para la segunda DB_2="", username_2="", password_2="", host_2="", se ve raro, pero puedes hacerte una funciona en JS que obtenga los datos de las variables de entorno segun sea el caso